# Pythonでfortran形式のデータを読み込む方法

Tags: python, テキストファイル, pandas, numpy

pythonでデータを読み込みこむ方法について質問します。
読み込むデータは、下記のようなfortran 80カラムのフォーマットで10f8.3の形式です。

```
   0.010   0.010   0.031   0.024   0.027  -0.030  -0.026   0.020  -0.119  -0.154
  -0.015  -0.081  -0.045  -0.016  -0.163  -0.179  -0.128  -0.104  -0.091  -0.164
  -0.216  -0.159  -0.212  -0.290  -0.169  -0.267  -0.288  -0.203  -0.304  -0.348
  -0.259  -0.284  -0.356  -0.261  -0.294  -0.260  -0.229  -0.259  -0.174  -0.240
  -0.231  -0.194  -0.162  -0.253  -0.264  -0.216  -0.248  -0.168  -0.227  -0.265
.....
```

と5000個のデータが並んでいます。

これを先頭行より順に1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10とカラム方向に読み込んで配列に入れたいのですが。
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
numpyがいいのか？pandasを使えばよいのか？
ご教示のほどよろしくお願いします。

Comment: pandas であれば `pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=' ', header=None, skipinitialspace=True)` でしょうか。ただ、pandas の場合はリストではなくデータフレームになります。リストで欲しい場合は、`pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=' ', header=None, skipinitialspace=True).values.tolist()` などとします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。delimiterがspace,tab,commaなどでない場合は、例えば、8character毎に分けて読む方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: `[[l[s:s+8] for s in range(0, len(l), 8)] for l in open('data.csv').read().splitlines()]` でしょうか。戻り値は str 型の2次元配列になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　早速試してみます。

Comment: d=[[l[s:s+8] for s in range(0, len(l), 8)] for l in open('g:\\data.txt').read().splitlines()] list = [flatten for inner in d for flatten in inner]  f_float = map(float,list) でfloat型の1次元listを取得できました。　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

```
d = [[l[s:s+8] for s in range(0, len(l), 8)] for l in open('g:\\data.txt').read().splitlines()]
list = [flatten for inner in d for flatten in inner]
f_float = map(float,list)
```

でfloat型の1次元listを取得できたそうです。